# jquery add class

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

Helo folks.,

i am using jquery.cycle plugin for displaying image gallery..

i have a navigation in this gallery.

i need to add class(Active) for current displayed image in the navigation ?

any pointer?

```
$(function() {
    var bc = $('#nav');
    var $container = $("ul#slides").cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        pause: 1,
        before: addTitle
    });

    $container.children().each(function(i) { //    Navigation part
        $('<li><a>&nbsp;</a></li>').appendTo(bc).click(function() {
            $container.cycle(i);
            return false;
        });
        $("#nav li a").first().addClass("active");

    });

    function addTitle() {
        $("#nav li a.active").removeClass("active").next().add("#nav li a").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

thank you

Comment: can you please show html (where images is)?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You ask about adding the class for the currently displayed image (`<img/>`), but your code shows you adding/removing the class from anchor elements (`<a>`).

Comment: yes..for currently displayed image i want my navigation items to display active class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to use `activePagerClass` and `pager` option for this?

For examlpe:

```
var $container = $("ul#slides").cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    activePagerClass: 'active',
    pause: 1,
    pager: '#nav'
});
```

You can see [example here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager7.html)